# "Invalid field for upsert, must be an External Id custom or standard indexed field: Name" error

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to enter unique values to the Contact object. Here is the code:

```
List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact> {
        new Contact(FirstName='Joe',LastName='Smith',Department='Finance'),
        new Contact(FirstName='Kathy',LastName='Smith',Department='Technology'),
        new Contact(FirstName='Caroline',LastName='Roth',Department='Finance'),
        new Contact()};   

// Caroline Roth already exists so I want this code to update her record, not insert another Caroline Roth record          
Database.UpsertResult[] srList = Database.upsert(conList, Contact.Fields.Name, false);
```

Salesforce's documentation states
"The upsert statement matches the sObjects with existing records by comparing values of one field. If you don’t specify a field when calling this statement, the upsert statement uses the sObject’s ID to match the sObject with existing records in Salesforce. Alternatively, you can specify a field to use for matching. For custom objects, specify a custom field marked as external ID. For standard objects, you can specify any field that has the idLookup property set to true. For example, **the Email field of Contact** or User has the idLookup property set."

I have two questions:
1) how can we see which fields on the Contact object have their idLookup property set to true
2) why am I getting the error in the subject line when I execute the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> contacFieldsMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Contact').getDescribe().fields.getMap();

for (Schema.SObjectField field : contacFieldsMap.values()) {
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = field.getDescribe();
    if (fieldResult.isIdLookup()) System.debug(fieldResult.getName() + ' IS idLookup');
}
```

2: `System.debug(Contact.Name.getDescribe().isIdLookup());  // false`